# Turn on camera flash in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is is possible to turn on the camera's flash in WP7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now possible in the Windows Phone OS 7.1 SDK.

Here's the link to the MSDN article: [Access Camera API on WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202949.aspx)

```
PhotoCamera cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done programatically in the current SDK.

The user is in exclusive control of this feature on their phone.

Comment: Although OEMs like HTC are able to do this as they are allowed more access to the phone, their Flashlight app uses this ability, others can't (although it would be nice).

Comment: Does anyone know if developers have access to the camera flash now with the 7.1?

Comment: Suposidly, yes, but I can't figure out how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.flashmode(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) In the main page XAML file, MainPage.xaml, add the following code in the StackPanel element, below the Button element named ShutterButton. This code is the button for the camera flash.

```
<Button Name="FlashButton" Content="Fl:TBD" Click="changeFlash_Clicked" FontSize="26" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Height="75"/>
```

2) Open the code-behind file for the main page, MainPage.xaml.cs, and add the following variable declarations above the MainPage class constructor:

// Holds current flash mode.

```
private string currentFlashMode;
```

3) In MainPage.xaml.cs, add the following code to the OnNavigatedTo method, just below the Disable UI comment.

```
FlashButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

4) In MainPage.xaml.cs, add the following code to the cam_Initialized method, just below the txtDebug statement:

// Set flash button text.

```
FlashButton.Content = "Fl:" + cam.FlashMode.ToString();
```

This code displays the current flash mode on the FlashButton button.

5) In MainPage.xaml.cs, add the following code to the MainPage class. This code implements the event handler for changeFlash_Clicked by switching to a different flash mode each time the button is pressed.

```
// Activate a flash mode.
// Cycle through flash mode options when the flash button is pressed.
private void changeFlash_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    switch (cam.FlashMode)
    {
        case FlashMode.Off:
            if (cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.On))
            {
                // Specify that flash should be used.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.On;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:On";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: On";
            }
            break;
        case FlashMode.On:
            if (cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.RedEyeReduction))
            {
                // Specify that the red-eye reduction flash should be used.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.RedEyeReduction;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:RER";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: RedEyeReduction";
            }
            else if (cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.Auto))
            {
                // If red-eye reduction is not supported, specify automatic mode.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Auto;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:Auto";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: Auto";
            }
            else 
            {
                // If automatic is not supported, specify that no flash should be used.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:Off";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: Off";
            }
            break;
        case FlashMode.RedEyeReduction:
            if (cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.Auto))
            {
                // Specify that the flash should be used in the automatic mode.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Auto;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:Auto";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: Auto";
            }
            else
            {
                // If automatic is not supported, specify that no flash should be used.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:Off";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: Off";
            }
            break;
        case FlashMode.Auto:
            if (cam.IsFlashModeSupported(FlashMode.Off))
            {
                // Specify that no flash should be used.
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
                FlashButton.Content = "Fl:Off";
                currentFlashMode = "Flash mode: Off";
            }
            break;
    }

    // Display current flash mode.
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
    {
        txtDebug.Text = currentFlashMode;
    });
}
```